# How do I create a circular foreign key dependency in PostgresQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been working on PostgreSQL and I'm having trouble with this question:

Can someone lead me on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: First step would be to create 2 tables.  DO you know how to do that ?

Comment: Is this homework or an assignment? It reads like it. What've you already tried? What reading did you do?

Comment: Also: Where is this this question from? You clearly didn't write the question (different writing style, phrasing, etc) ... is it coursework?

Comment: Geez, you didn't even bother checking for the correct syntax in the manual did you?

Comment: Ah, the good old days of kicking around askers.  Such a carefree time...

Answer (score 10):

It isn't clear from your question, but I'm guessing you can't figure out how to create the circular dependency in order to test it. I won't give you the exact commands since this looks like homework and you've made no effort with your question, but here's a hint:

- Create `first_table`, making sure to include a primary key
- Create `second_table`, making sure to include a primary key and another column that is a foreign key reference to `first_table`'s primary key column.
- Now `ALTER TABLE first_table`, adding a new column that is a foreign key reference to `second_table`'s primary key column.

Now, insert a row into one of them, or try to.

I strongly suggest that you read the manual:

- [PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html)
- [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)
- [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)
- [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html)
- [`INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

Note that you *can* actually create a valid circular dependency between rows in two tables by making one or both of the foreign key constraints `DEFERRED`. See [`SET CONSTRAINTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-constraints.html). This can be exceedingly useful when you wish to create a mandatory `1:n` relationship, where *at least one `n` must exist*.

Comment: You don't need to add the FK *column* in a second step. You just need to add the FK *constraint* after the second table is created.

Comment: From what I tried, I did something like, create table C(cc int(3) primary key

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah - I just didn't want to explain both, and figured adding a column with FK ref was easier to understand than adding a constraint to an existing Col